# Revalidate Tag in nextJs in not working as expected

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have 2 functions, One gets all the leaves, and another used to update the leave status. I want to revalidate and call getLeaves each time updateLeave is called to show latest data in my UI.

```
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache";

export const getLeaveRequests = async () => {
    revalidateTag("leaves");
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROD_API_URL}/leaves`,
            {
                cache: "no-cache",
            }
        );

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to fetch employees data");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while fetching employee data:", error);
    }
};


export const updateLeaveRequest = async (data: any) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROD_API_URL}/leaves/update`,
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                next: {
                    tags: ["leaves"],
                },
            }
        );

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to fetch employees data");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while fetching employee data:", error);
    }
};
```

In the above, I have added next:{tags:["leaves"]} in the update call and revaldating that tag in get call. But my UI still stays the same, and changes only upon refresh.
**
UI code:**

```
`async function page() {
    const leaveRequests = await getLeaveRequests();
    return (
        <div>
            <DataTableWithFilters
                title="Leave Request"
                buttonText="leave"
                columns={leaveRequestColumns}
                data={leaveRequests}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default page;`
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the updateLeaveRequest , make sure to invoke the revalidateTag('leaves') in a server action to revalidate the Data cache and Router cache to reflect the results immediately on the UI.